# Locate a variable in between Javascript variable using angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this code in Angular JS, I pass the `AnsOptions` as an object from controller:

```
   <ion-list>
     <ion-item  ng-click="checkAnswer(CurrentQuestionIdIndex)" class="chat-item ng-enter-stagger item-remove-animate" ng-repeat="AnsOption in AnsOptions">
       <div style="float:left; width:10%;">
          {{AnsOption.alphabet}}
       </div>
       <div style="float:left; width:90%;">
          <div ng-bind-html="question.option1_bm"></div> //This line
       </div>
            </ion-item>
       </ion-list>
```

Well I got stuck to put `AnsOption.index` in between the code `question.option1_bm`.

My expected result will be like below:

```
<div ng-bind-html="question.option1_bm"></div>
<div ng-bind-html="question.option2_bm"></div>
<div ng-bind-html="question.option3_bm"></div>
<div ng-bind-html="question.option4_bm"></div>
```

In Angularjs, how I can do this? This what I had tried so far:

```
<div ng-bind-html="question.option[AnsOption.index]_bm"></div>
```

But does not work at all. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Use `$index` property of `ng-repeat` like below

```
<div ng-repeat="AnsOption in AnsOptions">
  {{$index}}
</div>
```

**In your case**:

```
<ion-list>
     <ion-item  ng-click="checkAnswer(CurrentQuestionIdIndex)" class="chat-item ng-enter-stagger item-remove-animate" ng-repeat="AnsOption in AnsOptions">
       <div style="float:left; width:10%;">
          {{AnsOption.alphabet}}
       </div>
       <div style="float:left; width:90%;">
          <div ng-bind-html="'question.option'+($index+1)+'_bm'"></div> //This line
       </div>
            </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: still not work... the string cannot convert to variable at all